# Impact of Unlocked Package still installed and Classes are added to Salesforce org

Tags: salesforcedx, integration, unlocked-package

Background:

There is a salesforce production org that has both an unlocked package with integrationClassOne in it, installed in productive and integrationClassOne is created and deployed into production outside of the managed package.

The unlocked package process was used for the initial deployment of the code, however, pivoted to a different form of deployment due to struggles with the unlocked package process early on (a separate issue I understand.)

In the pivot, the unlocked package was shelved but never uninstalled from the production org. and the Classes have been deployed through the SDLC process using metadata API.

1. What is the impact of updating just the integrationClassOne via sandbox only and not updating the unlocked package?

Answer (score 1):

Deployments made after installation will override what was in the package. Installation of an updated package version would override the last deployed version. There's nothing you need to worry about if you never plan on installing a new version.